# Android <unknown> Genre in MediaStore

Tags: android

Is there a way to query for genres in MediaStore and also find songs that don't have a genre set?

This code returns all songs that have a genre set but skips those that don't have a genre.

```
String[] proj1 = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID
    };
ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
genreCursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj1, null, null, null);
if (genreCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (genreCursor.moveToNext()) {
        int index = genreCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME);
        String genre = genreCursor.getString(index);
        index = genreCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID);
        long genreId = Long.parseLong(genreCursor.getString(index));
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external", genreId);
        Cursor tempCursor = cr.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (tempCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (tempCursor.moveToNext()) {
                index = tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                String title = tempCursor.getString(index);
                index = tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST);
                String artist = tempCursor.getString(index);
                index = tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM);
                String album = tempCursor.getString(index);
                songs.add(new Song(artist, title, album, genre));
            }
            tempCursor.close();
        }
    }
```

I am looking for a way to find those songs that have an unknown genre set. Is the only possibility to query all songs and then cross-check them with those that have a genre set to have a list of all songs with the genre for those that have it set?

Answer (score 0):

Songs with unknown genre will have genre as "unknown". So, you'll be getting the the list of all the songs on the device.

Comment: No, the genreCursor does not iterate over an "unknown" genre unfortunately. It just iterates over known genres.

Comment: Unknown is a known genre

Comment: No. This code does not read Unknown genre. It just skips all songs with an Unknown genre.

Comment: if you loop through the list of songs in the device the meta data shows genre as "unknown" not sure why its not listed in the genre list.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to scan all the songs with genres and store it in SQLitedatabase. Hope this will help you and this code also return  genres.

```
        int index;
        int genres;
        long genreId;
        int count;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor genrecursor;
        Cursor musicCursor;
        db = new DBhelper(getApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase();
        String[] proj1 = {MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID};

        genrecursor=getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj1,null, null, null);
        if(genrecursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                genres = genrecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME);
                System.out.println("GENRE NAME: "+genrecursor.getString(genres));
                System.out.println("======================================");

                index = genrecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID);
                genreId=Long.parseLong(genrecursor.getString(index));
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external", genreId);

                musicCursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,null,null);
                System.out.println("Total Songs: "+musicCursor.getCount());
                if(musicCursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                    int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                    int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                    int albumId = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
                    int data = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                    int albumkey = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_KEY);
                    int albumName = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
                    int artwork = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);


                    do{
                        long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                        String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                        String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                        long thisalbumId = musicCursor.getLong(albumId);
                        String thisdata = musicCursor.getString(data);
                        String AlbumKey = musicCursor.getString(albumkey);
                        String thisAlbum = musicCursor.getString(albumName);
                         String thisGenres = genrecursor.getString(genres);





                        ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
                        value.put("songtitle", thisTitle);
                        value.put("songartist", thisArtist);
                        value.put("songpath", thisdata);
                        value.put("songalbum", thisAlbum);
                          value.put("songgenres", thisGenres);
                        try {
                            db.insertOrThrow("songListRecord", null, value);
                        }
                        catch (SQLiteConstraintException e)
                        {

                        }


                    }while(musicCursor.moveToNext());
                }
                System.out.println("======================================");
            }while(genrecursor.moveToNext());
        }
```